# What is the literal meaning of 'mind' in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Would you mind turning the music down?

> Would you mind helping me with this project?

Is the verb 'mind' about bothering or willing? What is the literal meaning of 'mind' in this context?

I know sentence's asking polite request but in case of translation, I need to know what does 'mind' exactly imply to use most suitable words in targeted language.

Comment: The literal meaning is that it's a polite request. That's how you should translate it, as a polite request in whatever language you are translating it into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The literal meaning is "be opposed to".

There is a sense development of mind:  From the basic sense of "think about", it developed the sense of "think negatively about" or "oppose".

So the person is asking whether the other person is opposed to turning down the music.  That is the basic meaning of "mind":  "be opposed to".  But the implication is that if you are not opposed, then you are willing, and there is an implied request: "... and if you don't mind turning down the music, please do it.

Comment: Thank you for your help sir.